# Ionic build failed: FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, braintree, ionic-native

It happens when i added braintree plugin.FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '...\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-braintree\bookmi-build-extras.gradle' line: 16
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> ...\platforms\android\app\res\xml\config.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Command failed with exit code 1: ...\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b ...\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: which command were you trying to run?

Comment: ionic cordova build android --prod